# Group by a period Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to group by a period of time the following table (example) :

```
------------------
|month|year|value|
------------------
|7    |2019|1.2  |
|8    |2019|1.7  |
|9    |2019|1.5  |
|10   |2019|0.7  |
|11   |2019|0.2  |
|12   |2019|1.7  |
|1    |2020|1.0  |
|2    |2020|0.1  |
|3    |2020|2.1  |
|4    |2020|1.2  |
|5    |2020|1.2  |
|6    |2020|1.7  |
|7    |2020|2.1  |
|8    |2020|1.7  |
|9    |2020|1.5  |
|10   |2020|0.7  |
|11   |2020|0.2  |
|12   |2020|1.7  |
|1    |2021|1.0  |
|2    |2021|0.1  |
|3    |2021|2.1  |
|4    |2021|1.2  |
|5    |2021|1.7  |
|6    |2021|1.5  |
Etc..
```

I have to group every 12 month from july(7) to June(6 of the next year).

I already tried some solution found online but nothing work for me, anyone have a solution?

I'm using Postgresql.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the solution that you tried? This will make it much easier to help find the mistake in that solution and have it return the result you desire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use arithmetic

```
select floor((year * 12 + month - 7) / 12) as effective_year, avg(value)
from t
group by effective_year;
```

Comment: Formula needs to be "floor((year * 12 + month - 7) / 12)" to force June (06) into prior effective_year.

Answer (score 0):

@GordonLinoff has the appropriate solution missing only the actual period covered by the effective_year. However, that period is easily derived using the effective_year and a couple built in functions: [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) and [make_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html).

```
select daterange(make_date(effective_year  ,07 ,01)  
                ,make_date(effective_year+1,06 ,30) 
                ,'[]'
                )
     , avg_value
  from (select floor((year * 12 + month - 7) / 12)::integer as effective_year
             , avg(value) avg_value
          from test_data
         group by effective_year 
       ) da
 order by effective_year;
```

See full [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f0983540993105ed58c6fe3584a54bf6).